# Como puedo formular una REGEX que capture la primera coincidencia detras de una palabra

Tags: regex

Necesito ayuda con una Expresión regular.

Por ejemplo, tengo el siguiente texto:

```
... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit
%ID%1%ID%
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
%ID%2%ID%
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
%ID%3%ID%
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla **PALABRA** pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
%ID%4%ID%
mollit anim id est laborum...
```

Quisiera formular una expresión regular que capture el número que está entre "%ID%" y "%ID%" justo detrás de la palabra buscada, que en este caso es "PALABRA".

En el caso anterior la salida seria "3".

La expresión regular que tengo es:

```
\%ID\%(\d)+\%ID\%[\S\s]*\bPALABRA\b
```

pero captura todo desde "%ID%1%ID%".

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Tus ejemplos están bien?  Porque no logro entender como sacas el 2 por ejemplo.

Comment: Quisiera sacar el 2. Con la exp regular que uso solo me saca todo el texto hasta el 1. https://regex101.com/r/ApVJ09/1/

Comment: Pero justo detrás de la palabra buscada PALABRA sería el 4 y justo antes de la palabra sería el 3. No entiendo cuál de los dos casos quieres.

Comment: La pregunta es poco clara, porque ademas regex lo que hace es buscar si una cadena concuerda o no con tu regex. En que lenguaje estas intentando esto? Estas cosas en general se solucionan mucho mas facil solo parseando la cadena.

Comment: Tienes razón Juan Carlos, es el 3 que estaría buscando en el ejemplo. Me he liado con otros ejemplos que estoy usando para intentar conseguir la respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con esta expresión regular puedes extraer el número entre %IDn%ID y tiene atrás la palabra de búsqueda.

```
(?:(\d+)(?:\%ID\%[^\%]*PALABRA))/gm
```

El resultado en este ejemplo se encuentra en el primer grupo $1=3, extraído de ID%3%ID% que tiene atrás la palabra de búsqueda.

Como no has puesto el lenguaje de programación no te dejo como extraerlo.

**EDICION:** Nueva versión que corrige por si viene un % entre la palabra buscada y el dígito.

```
(?:(\d+)\%ID\%)[\r\n]+?.*PALABRA/gm
```

o para asegurarte que el dígito se encuentre entre %ID:

```
(?:\%ID\%(\d+)\%ID\%)[\r\n]+?.*PALABRA/gm
```

NOTA: Si se encuentra la palabra en dos partes del párrafo entonces, tendrás arreglos donde el $1 es el numero que quieres. Depende del lenguaje en que lo hagas.

**EDICION:** Versión mejorada:

```
(?:%ID%(\d)%ID%)(([\s\S])(?<!%ID%\d%ID%))*PALABRA/gm
```

**EDICION:** Versión simplificada utilizando indicador **s**. Esta versión es de autoría del autor de la pregunta (ver comentarios).

```regex
%ID%(\d+)%ID%(?(?!%ID%).)*PALABRA/gs
```

**NOTA:**

En expresiones regulares siempre deben considerar los flags de la expresión. En esta respuesta se han utilizado:

- **g**:
  Indica que continúe tras encontrar el patrón, de lo contrario, solo evalúa hasta encontrar el primero.
- **m**:
  En este caso si el texto contiene una serie de líneas se consideren los retornos de línea para evaluar la expresión de inicio y a fin cada línea utilizando **^** y **$**. Este indicador pudo ser omitido en las anteriores versiones.
- **s:**
  Los caracteres de nueva línea son consideradas por  **punto (.)** utilizado para indicar que capture cualquier carácter menos el de  nueva línea a menos que se indique este indicador.

  **m** y **s** no son excluyentes.

Comment: Muy interesante Juan, casi listo, solo que si hay algún carácter % en el texto entre el ID y la palabra no consigue el número. por ejemplo, es valido que aparezca "con un 50% de descuento" entre la PALABRA a buscar y le ID. Un saludo.

Comment: Te actualizo la solución. El orden es el correcto?

Comment: Perdona, a que te refieres con el orden? si te refieres al ID, Si, debe dar $1=3 extrayendo desde ID%3%ID%, halla o no hallan símbolos como el "%". Gracias Juan, espero tu respuesta.

Comment: Así es. Es sacar el primero está delante de la palabra buscada cierto? He editado la respuesta.

Comment: Correcto, el más próximo hacia atrás,. He intentado agregando una línea entre el %ID%3%ID% y la PALABRA y ha dejado de funcionar.
https://regex101.com/r/HQkz9L/2

Comment: Edita la respuesta para mejorar la expresión

Comment: Gracias Juan, aunque he cambiado el id 3 (de 1 dígito) por 33 (2 o mas dígitos) y ha tomado el ID de arriba que tiene 1 dígito. He intentado colocarle los modificadores + y * en los \d, dentro y fuera de los paréntesis y no logro hacer que agarre los n dígitos que puede tener un %ID%. https://regex101.com/r/HQkz9L/4

Comment: Le he mostrado tu solución a un compañero y me ha resuelto el problema con la regex: %ID%(\d+)%ID%(?(?!%ID%).)*PALABRA
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y paciencia Juan. Si quieres pruebala a ver que tal y editas tu respuesta para que los demás usuario la puedan conseguir rápido.

Comment: Esa la había probado pero no me dio resultado y acabo de hacerlo y tampoco funciona, sin embargo, olvidé la existencia del indicador  **s** que me resuelve lo caracteres de nueva línea. Lo incluiré con las debidas referencias. Bueno, al menos me ha servido para nunca olvidarme de considerar los indicadores regex. Gracias.